# Single page application (SPA) на Github pages

Tags: javascript, html, github, spa

Есть несколько страниц с таблицами вида:

```
<body>
<script src="sorting.js"></script>
<table class="sort" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Столбец 1</td>
            <td>Столбец 2</td>               
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Значение 1</td>
            <td>Значение 2</td>               
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Сейчас каждая страница это отдельный документ .html

Все они разного размера и содержания, в каждой из них подключается одинаковая таблица стилей (css) и js скрип сортировки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать простенькое SPA, которое будет работать на Github pages. Желательно без AngularJS, React и прочих страшных слов (так как я не являюсь разработчиком мне будет сложно с этим разобраться)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть обычные страницы то не обязательно делать спа чтобы была навигация между ними. 
Есть технология [vuepress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/) с ней можно использовать markdown разметку, сделать много страниц, можно все настраивать, и сгенерировать готовый сайт в виде многостранычных хтмл файлов, что хорошо для сео. Сам их сайт написан на их библиотеке.